# Garmin Connect API for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I'm trying to create a library to download content from Garmin Connect.

There's not too much documentation, or is not public, but I tried to base my code on the great [Tapiriik project](https://github.com/cpfair/tapiriik/blob/master/tapiriik/services/GarminConnect/garminconnect.py)

It seems that the Garmin API needs to create a session (Based on BasicAutentication cookie) before be able to download the content.

I tried to do that using NSURLConnection and NSURLSession unsuccessfully (Sync/Async & With delegate and with CompletionHandler also tried).

```
// POST request with the params I have found on the tapiriik example
[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://connect.garmin.com/signin"]];
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"j_id1=javax.faces.ViewState&login=login&login:loginUsernameField=%@&login:password=%@&login:signInButton=Sign In", theUsername, thePassword];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

The response is a 200, and I checked the user profile and seem that works successfully. But If I tried to download the activity I receive a 403

```
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://connect.garmin.com/proxy/activity-search-service-1.2/json/activities?start=0&limit=10"]];
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

PD: I checked other github projects but all of them work in a similar way as tapiriik code

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it. It seems that Garmin has a new development policy.

Finally I follow the steps here: https://forums.garmin.com/showthread.php?72150-connect-garmin-com-signin-question&p=264580#post264580

I will upload the code to GitHub and share here.

Regards